# Git format-patch doesn't work with some variables

Tags: git, bash, sed

I wanted to use a script to create a patch of all my commits but `git format-patch` shows `fatal: bad revision` error in script. When I use output of sed it doesn't work but when I do it manually or set variable manually git format works just fine. I am on mac terminal.

Please help.

[image: Screenshot of my terminal]

`` git format-patch -1 `git log -1 --pretty=oneline | sed 's/ .*//'` -- `` also shows the error.
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Please don't post images. Use the code formatting to detail the steps/commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to read the image (not so bad when clicking on it) but the real giveaway is the colors.  When you do:

```
echo $a
```

the output, which starts with `c4e13`, is in yellow.  If you wrote:

```
echo c4e13
```

*that* output would be in white.

Rhetorical / Socratic question:  Why?  What is it about `$a` that causes the SHA-1 to be in yellow?

---

Answer: it contains some embedded color-switching ASCII control codes (escape, left-bracket, digits, letter-m probably).  These are not part of the SHA-1; they were produced by your `git log` because you forced it to produce color, even when output is going to a pipe.  (By default, git stops colorizing output when piping.)

Make sure you aren't capturing ANSI-terminal control-sequences when writing scripts (even simple ones like this one).  Note also that if you want to get the SHA-1 associated with `HEAD`, the "git plumbing command" (for writing scripts) that does this is `git rev-parse HEAD`.

Comment: Thank you. Adding `--no-color` to git log command worked for me.